# Python error "AttributeError: module 'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'logsumexp' "

Tags: python-3.x, lifetimes-python

I'm trying to use the lifetimes header to create the Recency, Frequency and T from a given data but it keeps showing the following error
AttributeError: module 'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'logsumexp'

```
from lifetimes.plotting import *
from lifetimes.utils import *
from lifetimes.estimation import *
data = summary_data_from_transaction_data(df, 'CustomerID','InvoiceDate', monetary_value_col='Sales', observation_period_end='2011-12-9')
print(data.head())
```

The following output is received:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "prj2.py", line 23, in <module>
from lifetimes.plotting import *
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\lifetimes\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from .fitters.beta_geo_fitter import BetaGeoFitter
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\lifetimes\fitters\beta_geo_fitter.py", line 9, in <module>
from autograd.scipy.special import gammaln, beta, gamma
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\autograd\scipy\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from . import misc
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\autograd\scipy\misc.py", line 7, in <module>
logsumexp = primitive(scipy.misc.logsumexp)
AttributeError: module 'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'logsumexp'
```

The version of SciPy is 1.3.0
The code should generate a table with Recency, Frequency and T of each Customer

Comment: show the code for summary_data_from_transaction_data() function.

Comment: The following function is not user defined. It's part of the library of lifetimes

Comment: can you print the stack trace of the error as well as the version of scipy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Downgrading to scipy==1.1.0 solves the issue

Answer (score 1):

Change `from scipy.misc import logsumexp`to `from scipy.special import logsumexp`

Comment: I tried both the solution, downgraded scipy version and changed to special instead of misc. But i still get same error. I am using this function on colab . Is there any other solution ?